# Logic Error, draw(Graphics g) fails to draw when called (Java)

Tags: java

I've found myself incapable of utilizing draw methods to display images within a JFrame. The code following functions exactly the same if the draw(Graphics p) method is never called. What is causing this lack of functionality, and what can be done to fix it? (Assuming that "C:\test\background.png" is a valid path.) There is no compile-time error, and no displayed run-time error. This is the only class in the program. Attempting to draw within a JPanel does nothing to repair the issue.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    private Image mainMenuBackground;
    private String state;
    Graphics g;

    Main(){
        setSize(800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        state = "main menu";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run();
    }
    public void loadImages(){
        mainMenuBackground = new ImageIcon("C:\\test\\background.png").getImage();
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            loadImages();
            draw(g);
            pack();
        }catch(Exception ex){}
    }
    public void draw(Graphics p){
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) p;
        g.drawImage(mainMenuBackground, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're trying to use made-up methods (draw?) to do Swing Graphics. Unfortunately there's a lot wrong with your program (trying to draw directly in a JFrame, storing a Graphics variable, not getting the Graphics object from the JVM via a JComponent's paintComponent method, and using it there...), and the best solution is to read the Swing graphics tutorials first. There's much to learn, but fortunately the tutorials are very good, and you so you won't regret going there. Please start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this:

```
catch(Exception ex){}
```

will stop you seeing *anything* that's going wrong. You say there's "no displayed run-time error" - well I'm not surprised, as you've suppressed everything.

Next, you're never assigning a value for the instance variable `g`, so it will still have a value of `null` when you pass it to the `draw` method, where you then use a *local* variable `g` of a different type... and dereference it. That will cause a `NullPointerException`, which you then catch and ignore.

So basically there's lots going wrong, but fundamentally you don't get to just declare a `Graphics` variable and hope that it'll have a useful value. For "normal" painting operations, the graphics context is *provided* to your method automatically - or you can create it when working with an image object.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. The tutorials I've been following keep telling me to just toss a full catch clause on everything. But how do I assign a value to a Graphics object? I can't find a valid constructor.

Comment: @Passage: the tutorials will show you all. Please start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: My apologies for asking such a foolish question. This should help. Thanks to the both of you.

Comment: @Passage: If you've been following exceptions suggesting that you catch all exceptions and then ignore them completely, you need to start reading different tutorials. It's a shame that there's such bad advice out there :( (I've seen plenty of other examples of awful advice in tech books...)

Comment: @Passage: it's not foolish at all, but GUI graphics programming takes a different mind set from the usual programming, one that may require you to throw out a bunch of assumptions before succeeding (I know that I sure had to) and it's something that you can't just jump in and swim without first reading the directions. Study the tut's and you should do well.